# Unit test exception-messages formatted with sprintf

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

How can I test if an exception throws the expected error message, when I format my error messages like this:

`throw new \Exception(sprintf('Random string: "%s".', 'blablabla'));`

Obviously testing with $this->assertEquals() won't work, since I don't know what `%s` is going to be. Is there a straight forward way to test Exception messages that use `sprintf`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you know what the value of `'%s'` is going to be? I thought that was one of the purposes of testing, to trigger certain parts of your code in controlled ways? Why can't you have your code raise a specific exception in the way you wnat it raised then you can assert the message is equal to what you expectd?

Comment: @dm03514: It's been a long day... Obviously that is the correct way to do it. I'll except it as an answer, if you post it as one.

Comment: Why not extend the exception, as `RandomStringException`? :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony: I used 'Random string' just as an example. As dm03514 already mentioned, I should actually know for each individual test what %s is going to be. Thanks for the suggestion though! It might help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you should know what `'%s'` is going to be by triggering the part of your code you want an exception in, in a controlled way.

You could trigger the exceptions you are expecting, then you can use `assertEquals` with the error message you are expecting to be triggered